# Rabbinic weights and measures in primary source

Tags: shiurim-measurements

Where can I find a concise presentation of the full system of rabbinic weights and measures, in a primary source?

Meaning X tefachim in an Amah, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that they're rabbinic?

Comment: Good question.  Some of the words are biblical.  I was presuming that they were systematized in the time of the Talmud.  I might have it a bit wrong.  I’ve seen charts in modern guides to Talmud, but I haven’t see a full presentation in a Rishon or Acharon.

Comment: What does primary source mean to you? You mention rishon/acharon in the comments, so why isn't a table (from the acharon era) sufficient?

Comment: In different Artscroll publications there are tables to compare the different measures, in their Rashi commentary I'm sure there's one somewhere.

Comment: There are 20th-century guides to the Talmud that have this. If I'm not mistaken, Rishonim and even Acharonim will generally stick to the subject at-hand. So if a Mishna deals with tefachim and etzba'os, the commentaries will help you with those -- but won't confuse with with how those convert to a *parsa* or *mahalach yom*. And a discussion on volumes or weights will deal only with those, and only those employed at the scale of the issue. (Yes I'm aware there's the Gemara in Psachim relating lengths to volumes...)